# Is it possible to use Timers in java?

Tags: java

Iwant to built the server which continuously keeps on checking the database for any updates available to notify for every five minutes. Is it possible to use timer for checking the database in the java as v can do in dot net. If anyone has idea to implement it please share it with me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use a combination, a javascript code to check the  server every 5 minute, and java checks the db for new entries on every request

Comment: @Ibu: Using database as event storage is a software design anti-pattern and should be avoided: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database-as-IPC

Answer (score 7):

Yes sure it is possible. I hope you are asking about scheduling jobs

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new YourTask(), seconds * 1000);
```

Take a look at [quartz scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) for a more sophisticated approach.

Answer (score 4):

You can schedule any operation in java using the [Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html). You can also use [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartzscheduler.org) .
I would go for Spring scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.

[java.util.Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

Comment: @MByD: I think OP needs something like watchDog or reverse ajax that keeps watching on database for new changes...... :-/

Comment: Not 100%, but java/.net/javascript - which one is the odd one out?  Also checking a DB from JS (browser?) seemed... unlikely.